# I collected the numpy array from my webcam in a file but it is stored with dots and creates a problem later

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I have appended the frame value which I got from my webcam  in a list named final_frame. And then , I am writing it to a file and by convering it to str. The in another code, I am opening the file and reading the values and I was trying to make a video from it.

When I open the file, in notepad or in code, I am seeing "....." in between the numpy arays. This is not allowing me to make a video out of it.

Please see the code and images below:

capturevideo.py:

```
import cv2 , time , numpy
video=  cv2.VideoCapture(0   , cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
a=1
final_frame =[]
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
# out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4v' , fourcc , 20.0 , (640 , 480))
while True:
    a = a+1
    check, frame = video.read()
    # print(check)

    grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    final_frame.append(grey)
    # out.write(frame)
    # time.sleep(3)
    cv2.imshow("capturing" , grey)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key==ord('q'):
        break
print(a)
video.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(type(final_frame))

with open ("numpyarrays.txt" , 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(final_frame))
```

the text file created which has many dots in between. This appears even if I open it on notepad or vscode.

```
[array([[ 90,  89,  80, ..., 172, 173, 175],
       [ 89,  88,  83, ..., 172, 172, 171],
       [ 89,  90,  83, ..., 169, 169, 167],
       ...,
       [ 47,  52,  53, ..., 124, 126, 128],
       [ 50,  55,  55, ..., 125, 129, 131],
       [ 52,  54,  53, ..., 128, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8), array([[100, 100, 101, ..., 169, 172, 168],
       [100, 100, 100, ..., 169, 172, 165],
       [103, 100,  95, ..., 173, 176, 173],
       ...,
       [ 44,  43,  47, ..., 115, 116, 125],
       [ 47,  49,  53, ..., 116, 121, 131],
       [ 53,  54,  58, ..., 121, 123, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 87,  91,  91, ..., 169, 168, 167],
       [ 93,  95,  95, ..., 169, 169, 168],
       [100, 100,  98, ..., 173, 171, 167],
       ...,
       [ 51,  52,  52, ..., 121, 121, 124],
       [ 58,  58,  57, ..., 129, 128, 129],
       [ 62,  61,  58, ..., 132, 129, 129]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 91,  93,  97, ..., 173, 170, 166],
       [ 92,  95,  98, ..., 173, 173, 167],
       [ 93,  96, 103, ..., 175, 172, 162],
       ...,
       [ 55,  55,  57, ..., 129, 131, 133],
       [ 59,  61,  62, ..., 129, 131, 131],
       [ 61,  62,  62, ..., 128, 130, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[101, 101, 101, ..., 167, 167, 168],
       [101, 102, 100, ..., 167, 167, 168],
       [ 98, 100,  95, ..., 168, 168, 171],
       ...,
       [ 55,  61,  58, ..., 128, 128, 128],
       [ 53,  54,  54, ..., 128, 128, 126],
       [ 52,  53,  51, ..., 128, 128, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 86,  90,  95, ..., 169, 169, 172],
       [ 84,  87, 102, ..., 167, 165, 173],
       [ 86,  87, 100, ..., 166, 168, 173],
       ...,
       [ 55,  52,  50, ..., 120, 124, 129],
       [ 55,  51,  50, ..., 121, 125, 128],
       [ 51,  50,  50, ..., 124, 128, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 96, 101, 102, ..., 173, 174, 172],
       [ 98, 102, 103, ..., 170, 172, 171],
       [ 96,  98, 102, ..., 163, 165, 164],
       ...,
       [ 52,  54,  61, ..., 124, 119, 128],
       [ 50,  57,  64, ..., 131, 124, 124],
       [ 50,  55,  62, ..., 133, 126, 123]], dtype=uint8), array([[102,  99,  95, ..., 173, 172, 169],
       [ 99,  98,  95, ..., 173, 175, 169],
       [ 98,  97,  96, ..., 168, 166, 168],
       ...,
       [ 50,  53,  54, ..., 125, 129, 131],
       [ 53,  59,  58, ..., 125, 129, 131],
       [ 58,  65,  65, ..., 123, 128, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[101, 102, 102, ..., 171, 171, 172],
       [100, 101, 101, ..., 170, 170, 174],
       [ 96,  97,  96, ..., 173, 169, 175],
       ...,
       [ 44,  45,  50, ..., 126, 129, 129],
       [ 47,  45,  46, ..., 128, 130, 130],
       [ 48,  45,  44, ..., 126, 129, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[101, 102, 102, ..., 167, 167, 166],
       [101, 109, 118, ..., 166, 171, 164],
       [100, 119, 118, ..., 164, 171, 172],
       ...,
       [ 50,  51,  51, ..., 127, 129, 130],
       [ 53,  52,  52, ..., 128, 128, 129],
       [ 52,  52,  53, ..., 129, 128, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[107, 104, 102, ..., 168, 169, 169],
       [105, 104, 101, ..., 169, 169, 167],
       [105,  99, 100, ..., 166, 161, 159],
       ...,
       [ 55,  57,  58, ..., 135, 129, 126],
       [ 58,  58,  59, ..., 125, 126, 124],
       [ 59,  60,  64, ..., 123, 123, 123]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95,  95,  96, ..., 171, 172, 174],
       [ 98, 100,  95, ..., 169, 165, 178],
       [100,  98,  96, ..., 166, 169, 178],
       ...,
       [ 51,  57,  61, ..., 124, 126, 129],
       [ 50,  54,  56, ..., 124, 125, 125],
       [ 50,  52,  51, ..., 123, 124, 123]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 96,  91,  93, ..., 165, 170, 167],
       [ 96,  95,  99, ..., 164, 165, 168],
       [102, 100, 101, ..., 164, 165, 161],
       ...,
       [ 52,  54,  53, ..., 125, 124, 126],
       [ 55,  58,  59, ..., 125, 125, 131],
       [ 58,  59,  60, ..., 126, 129, 133]], dtype=uint8), array([[103, 104, 103, ..., 165, 164, 165],
       [103, 102, 102, ..., 169, 164, 168],
       [ 98,  97,  97, ..., 171, 171, 171],
       ...,
       [ 58,  61,  55, ..., 125, 126, 123],
       [ 57,  57,  55, ..., 125, 125, 124],
       [ 47,  47,  54, ..., 126, 126, 128]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 99,  93,  91, ..., 174, 172, 169],
       [101,  95,  92, ..., 175, 171, 168],
       [100, 100,  94, ..., 168, 168, 167],
       ...,
       [ 51,  53,  54, ..., 126, 131, 132],
       [ 54,  57,  61, ..., 129, 129, 130],
       [ 61,  64,  68, ..., 130, 130, 129]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 96,  96, 100, ..., 171, 172, 172],
       [ 96,  97, 100, ..., 169, 173, 169],
       [ 98, 100, 108, ..., 162, 165, 168],
       ...,
       [ 46,  52,  52, ..., 132, 132, 132],
       [ 58,  59,  55, ..., 133, 132, 135],
       [ 58,  60,  58, ..., 135, 133, 135]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95,  98, 102, ..., 167, 165, 166],
       [ 95,  97, 101, ..., 165, 157, 166],
       [ 95,  96,  98, ..., 162, 162, 167],
       ...,
       [ 52,  54,  55, ..., 132, 133, 130],
       [ 50,  51,  51, ..., 133, 132, 134],
       [ 50,  53,  51, ..., 128, 129, 125]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 88,  95,  94, ..., 172, 167, 167],
       [ 88,  94,  95, ..., 165, 166, 167],
       [ 89,  91,  91, ..., 166, 167, 168],
       ...,
       [ 49,  51,  53, ..., 125, 125, 124],
       [ 48,  52,  55, ..., 125, 128, 128],
       [ 50,  53,  57, ..., 126, 129, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 88,  89,  89, ..., 173, 173, 174],
       [ 86,  86,  96, ..., 173, 175, 168],
       [ 93,  91,  93, ..., 172, 175, 167],
       ...,
       [ 55,  55,  53, ..., 125, 125, 126],
       [ 61,  57,  53, ..., 125, 129, 132],
       [ 62,  57,  53, ..., 128, 129, 129]], dtype=uint8), array([[100,  96,  96, ..., 172, 168, 164],
       [ 98,  99, 105, ..., 173, 168, 168],
       [ 97, 101, 108, ..., 168, 168, 171],
       ...,
       [ 44,  44,  47, ..., 123, 123, 125],
       [ 47,  48,  50, ..., 129, 125, 126],
       [ 54,  59,  55, ..., 127, 127, 127]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 88,  83,  82, ..., 171, 170, 168],
       [ 87,  84,  81, ..., 174, 169, 167],
       [ 90,  89,  87, ..., 167, 169, 168],
       ...,
       [ 74,  49,  52, ..., 125, 126, 128],
       [ 68,  34,  38, ..., 126, 128, 130],
       [ 67,  58,  48, ..., 126, 128, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 97,  96,  96, ..., 169, 168, 171],
       [ 96,  95,  95, ..., 168, 169, 173],
       [ 93,  91,  95, ..., 169, 171, 169],
       ...,
       [ 50,  47,  47, ..., 129, 129, 122],
       [ 50,  47,  47, ..., 131, 130, 121],
       [ 55,  52,  51, ..., 131, 131, 125]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95,  93,  91, ..., 167, 168, 168],
       [ 96,  94,  90, ..., 166, 167, 171],
       [100,  96,  90, ..., 165, 172, 171],
       ...,
       [ 57,  57,  57, ..., 123, 124, 123],
       [ 61,  58,  55, ..., 124, 124, 121],
       [ 61,  58,  53, ..., 125, 125, 118]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 96,  96,  98, ..., 172, 173, 172],
       [ 97,  98,  91, ..., 172, 172, 171],
       [ 97, 110, 102, ..., 172, 173, 171],
       ...,
       [ 48,  55,  59, ..., 123, 124, 132],
       [ 53,  59,  61, ..., 124, 124, 130],
       [ 54,  60,  61, ..., 124, 123, 128]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 93, 101, 107, ..., 170, 169, 170],
       [ 93, 100, 103, ..., 170, 174, 167],
       [ 94,  96, 100, ..., 171, 172, 167],
       ...,
       [ 53,  54,  58, ..., 125, 125, 128],
       [ 57,  58,  58, ..., 126, 128, 130],
       [ 58,  58,  57, ..., 121, 126, 131]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 88,  86,  91, ..., 168, 166, 168],
       [ 89,  87,  93, ..., 171, 169, 165],
       [ 90,  89,  94, ..., 175, 171, 166],
       ...,
       [ 54,  57,  62, ..., 130, 129, 129],
       [ 54,  61,  65, ..., 130, 130, 129],
       [ 59,  61,  62, ..., 125, 128, 125]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 97,  98, 104, ..., 174, 172, 167],
       [ 96,  98, 101, ..., 174, 173, 168],
       [ 93,  96,  96, ..., 173, 175, 173],
       ...,
       [ 54,  38,  58, ..., 128, 132, 128],
       [ 53,  51,  59, ..., 127, 129, 127],
       [ 59,  57,  58, ..., 127, 126, 125]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95, 101, 103, ..., 173, 176, 175],
       [ 93,  95, 100, ..., 172, 176, 176],
       [ 89,  87,  93, ..., 173, 177, 175],
       ...,
       [ 55,  57,  59, ..., 125, 125, 127],
       [ 60,  61,  61, ..., 126, 128, 130],
       [ 64,  62,  60, ..., 128, 128, 129]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95,  96,  90, ..., 170, 167, 165],
       [ 96,  97,  93, ..., 169, 166, 165],
       [ 97,  98,  97, ..., 169, 165, 167],
       ...,
       [ 52,  51,  52, ..., 121, 122, 116],
       [ 51,  50,  51, ..., 121, 124, 121],
       [ 54,  47,  47, ..., 117, 124, 124]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 87,  89,  92, ..., 177, 176, 177],
       [ 89,  96,  95, ..., 176, 176, 180],
       [ 88,  93,  94, ..., 177, 176, 177],
       ...,
       [ 55,  58,  57, ..., 132, 131, 125],
       [ 58,  58,  58, ..., 128, 130, 125],
       [ 58,  59,  58, ..., 129, 128, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 94,  96, 101, ..., 169, 170, 169],
       [ 95,  97, 100, ..., 169, 169, 166],
       [ 96,  98, 100, ..., 173, 167, 165],
       ...,
       [ 43,  45,  54, ..., 135, 131, 131],
       [ 48,  51,  56, ..., 130, 128, 129],
       [ 53,  54,  55, ..., 131, 129, 129]], dtype=uint8), array([[101,  98,  98, ..., 169, 165, 166],
       [100,  96,  97, ..., 171, 173, 167],
       [ 95,  95,  96, ..., 169, 174, 170],
       ...,
       [ 54,  55,  59, ..., 129, 125, 129],
       [ 55,  57,  59, ..., 124, 124, 129],
       [ 55,  58,  58, ..., 130, 130, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 89,  91,  94, ..., 169, 167, 167],
       [ 87,  89,  91, ..., 169, 169, 167],
       [ 86,  83,  91, ..., 172, 171, 169],
       ...,
       [ 51,  53,  54, ..., 132, 125, 125],
       [ 59,  58,  54, ..., 138, 131, 130],
       [ 64,  62,  55, ..., 121, 125, 128]], dtype=uint8), array([[103, 102,  99, ..., 170, 172, 172],
       [102, 109, 111, ..., 171, 172, 172],
       [102, 117, 115, ..., 171, 167, 169],
       ...,
       [ 46,  57,  62, ..., 125, 128, 126],
       [ 47,  36,  60, ..., 124, 125, 126],
       [ 53,  53,  61, ..., 123, 123, 124]], dtype=uint8), array([[104,  98,  97, ..., 167, 169, 167],
       [104,  98,  96, ..., 167, 169, 165],
       [103,  99,  97, ..., 168, 169, 170],
       ...,
       [ 44,  44,  44, ..., 128, 134, 132],
       [ 46,  46,  45, ..., 135, 140, 137],
       [ 50,  50,  46, ..., 130, 136, 131]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 88,  89,  93, ..., 169, 168, 166],
       [ 93,  93,  93, ..., 168, 167, 166],
       [ 95,  97,  95, ..., 171, 171, 171],
       ...,
       [ 53,  52,  53, ..., 126, 131, 136],
       [ 66,  62,  58, ..., 124, 129, 133],
       [ 69,  62,  59, ..., 122, 125, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95, 103, 102, ..., 169, 173, 174],
       [ 98, 103, 102, ..., 164, 172, 169],
       [ 98, 101, 101, ..., 166, 171, 169],
       ...,
       [ 50,  33,  59, ..., 118, 122, 121],
       [ 55,  58,  67, ..., 119, 118, 124],
       [ 55,  59,  66, ..., 124, 128, 129]], dtype=uint8), array([[102, 102, 104, ..., 168, 169, 167],
       [103, 102, 109, ..., 171, 171, 172],
       [102, 100, 100, ..., 168, 169, 168],
       ...,
       [ 54,  58,  54, ..., 126, 136, 132],
       [ 60,  61,  58, ..., 131, 139, 138],
       [ 62,  62,  59, ..., 132, 131, 132]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 90,  94,  95, ..., 166, 169, 172],
       [ 93,  94,  95, ..., 165, 170, 172],
       [102,  98,  95, ..., 166, 160, 164],
       ...,
       [ 50,  48,  52, ..., 135, 128, 128],
       [ 55,  51,  55, ..., 139, 131, 129],
       [ 57,  55,  62, ..., 129, 128, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 95,  94,  93, ..., 167, 165, 168],
       [ 94,  95,  95, ..., 168, 167, 168],
       [ 93,  96,  95, ..., 165, 167, 168],
       ...,
       [ 60,  62,  60, ..., 125, 128, 129],
       [ 61,  62,  61, ..., 125, 128, 128],
       [ 62,  61,  61, ..., 125, 125, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[104, 100,  95, ..., 177, 176, 175],
       [104,  98,  95, ..., 176, 176, 172],
       [103, 100,  99, ..., 171, 168, 169],
       ...,
       [ 60,  61,  88, ..., 128, 129, 129],
       [ 60,  59,  75, ..., 130, 130, 129],
       [ 60,  54,  54, ..., 128, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 96,  93,  90, ..., 172, 174, 169],
       [ 98,  97,  93, ..., 171, 169, 167],
       [ 97,  97,  97, ..., 167, 166, 166],
       ...,
       [ 43,  51,  57, ..., 128, 125, 122],
       [ 48,  51,  55, ..., 121, 123, 124],
       [ 59,  54,  55, ..., 122, 124, 126]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 99,  95,  94, ..., 169, 167, 166],
       [ 97,  95,  92, ..., 168, 166, 167],
       [ 93,  93,  88, ..., 168, 166, 167],
       ...,
       [ 48,  50,  58, ..., 124, 135, 133],
       [ 52,  53,  58, ..., 119, 133, 135],
       [ 51,  56,  60, ..., 135, 138, 139]], dtype=uint8), array([[102, 101,  98, ..., 168, 171, 171],
       [101, 102, 102, ..., 168, 166, 174],
       [101, 107, 104, ..., 168, 167, 172],
       ...,
       [ 54,  55,  58, ..., 129, 125, 124],
       [ 55,  58,  59, ..., 137, 130, 128],
       [ 55,  59,  60, ..., 132, 131, 130]], dtype=uint8), array([[100, 102, 100, ..., 171, 169, 169],
       [101, 100,  97, ..., 172, 171, 171],
       [101,  98,  96, ..., 172, 171, 172],
       ...,
       [ 53,  52,  52, ..., 131, 131, 131],
       [ 54,  53,  51, ..., 126, 128, 130],
       [ 57,  55,  52, ..., 124, 126, 128]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 88,  90,  90, ..., 173, 173, 174],
       [ 95,  95,  91, ..., 173, 173, 169],
       [105,  97,  90, ..., 178, 171, 171],
       ...,
       [ 45,  45,  46, ..., 121, 125, 124],
       [ 46,  47,  47, ..., 130, 130, 126],
       [ 44,  48,  51, ..., 129, 131, 128]], dtype=uint8)]
```

And because of that, when I am running another code(torun.py) - I am getting this error:

The code - torun.py

```
import cv2, numpy, time
with open ("numpyarrays.txt" , 'r') as file:
    cont = file.read()
    print(type(cont))
    frame = numpy.asarray(cont)
    print(type(frame))
frame = frame.astype(numpy.uint8)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4v' , fourcc , 20.0 , (640 , 480))
out.write(frame)
out.release()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torun.py", line 7, in <module>
    frame = frame.astype(numpy.uint8)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[array([[ 90,  89,  80, ..., 172, 173, 175],\n       
[ 89,  88,  83, ..., 172, 172, 171],\n       [ 89,  90,  83, ..., 169, 169, 167],\n       ...,\n       [ 47,  52,  53, ..., 124, 126, 128],\n
```

if I remove the line  - frame = frame.astype(numpy.uint8) , I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torun.py", line 11, in <module>
    out.write(frame)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'image'
```

The root cause of this is the dots which are appearing in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
file.write(str(final_frame))
```

You **cannot** just use `str` to convert any given thing into something writable to the file. There is a difference between the thing itself, and a representation of the thing.

`final_frame` is a native Python list, that contains Numpy arrays. Numpy provides [a few different](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html) functions to save its data into files, in a way that preserves all information and can be read back later. (You need to read the documentation and choose what is most appropriate for you.) But this is complicated by having a list of those arrays. It would be better to make a single Numpy array with one extra dimension, by stacking those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that `str(array)` returns a string with dots for legibility. The most effficient way to do such a thing is to use the `np.load` and `np.save` functions, which are by the way way faster than storing it in a text file. Hence, what you want to do is replacing:

```py
with open ("numpyarrays.txt" , 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(final_frame))
```

by:

```py
np.save("numpyarrays.npy", final_frame)
```

and replacing:

```py
with open ("numpyarrays.txt" , 'r') as file:
    cont = file.read()
    print(type(cont))
    frame = numpy.asarray(cont)
    print(type(frame))
frame = frame.astype(numpy.uint8)
```

by:

```py
frame = np.load("numpyarrays.npy")
```

Comment: Please see the latest response i added to this question. THere I have pasted the new code and the error. Please help me out of the problem.